# Parse.Initialize throws IOException with Parse .NET SDK on .NET Core 2.2 hosted on Heroku

Tags: c#, heroku, parse-platform, .net-core, back4app

The following code

```
ParseClient.Initialize (new ParseClient.Configuration
{
    ApplicationID = "APPID",
    Key = ".NET KEY",
    ServerURI = "SERVER URL"
});
```

throws `System.IO.IOException: The file '/app/heroku_output/[HEROKU APP NAME]' already exists.`

Stack trace:

```
at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
at Parse.Internal.Utilities.StorageManager.get_PersistentStorageFileWrapper()
at Parse.Common.Internal.StorageController..ctor()
at Parse.Core.Internal.ParseCorePlugins.get_StorageController()
at Parse.Core.Internal.ParseCorePlugins.get_CurrentUserController()
at Parse.Core.Internal.ParseCorePlugins.<get_SubclassingController>b__54_0()
at Parse.Core.Internal.ObjectSubclassingController.RegisterSubclass(Type type)
at Parse.ParseClient.Initialize(Configuration configuration)
at api.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /tmp/build_ee0c61a720b09ce072787bbc64b4001d/Startup.cs:line 50
```

- .NET Core 2.2.104
- Heroku with buildpack https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack#v2.2.102
- Parse .NET SDK v2.0.0 (built from master branch at https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET)

Comment: What is the Server URL that you're using?

Comment: @nataliec I'm using `https://parseapi.back4app.com/` It's all working locally, but not on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't allow to write anything to the file system https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think that is the case here. The page you linked to only states that files written are deleted when the dyno is recycled, not that it is prohibited to write to the file system. In this case, without me knowing exactly, I bet it tries to store some kind of session state, hence this happens in the init method, and there's no problem with these files being recycled as the init method runs on each startup.

Comment: Could you please share an example on Github with the bug reproducing?